# toggle css as well as show/hide jquery

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I've got this bit of code working so that it toggles a show/hide and also changes the CSS elements...

I would like it to change back the :hover state with the toggle. Is that possible?

```
$("article").click(function () {
    $(".folder-items",this).slideToggle("slow");
    $("article:hover").css({
       background : 'none',
       border : '1px solid #C7C6C7'
    });
 });
```

How do I do this? What do I need to change?

I've basically hashed this code together from the docs and online resources. So not sure what to do to get it working right. I'm a little new to jquery.

Comment: Remove the `§` from the `border` property..

Comment: Uhm, open your text editor, move the caret to the end of line 5, go back one character, and press backspace.

Comment: ah, got it. edited that, still doesn't toggle the CSS :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
var origBg = $("article:hover").css('background');
var origBorder =  $("article:hover").css('border');

$("article").click(function () {
    $(".folder-items",this).slideToggle("slow");
    if ($("article:hover").css('border')==origBorder)
    {
        $("article:hover").css({
            background : 'none',
            border : '1px solid #C7C6C7'
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $("article:hover").css({
            background : origBg,
            border : origBorder
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `.toggleClass()` would do you wonders.

Define default CSS rules for your elements, as well as an auxiliary class that overrides those rules. Then use `.toggleClass()` to toggle that auxiliary class on / off.

```
// CSS
article {
    background-image:url(foo.png);
    border-style:none;
}

article.hovering {
   background:none;
   border:1px solid #c7c6c7;
}

// JS (jQuery 1.7.x)
$('article').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('hovering')
           .find('folder-items')
                .slideToggle('slow');
});
```

But, of course, you could always just leave the style toggles to CSS with a well-targeted `article:hover` rule. Take note that that doesn't work with older versions of IE though.